# How far should a model go in MVC programming?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I know a controller does the controlling, and model does the database stuff.

How far should the model go though?

If I have an array:

```
array( 'first_name' => 'Thomas', 'second_name' => 'Clayson', 'email' => 'thomas@email.com' );
```

And this is the mysql query I need to get out of it:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ("Thomas Clayson", "thomas@email.com");
```

What should my model look like?

## Take raw data and format appropriately

```
public function insertUser($details){
    if(!isset($details['first_name']) || !isset($details['second_name']) || !isset($details['email'])){
        return false;
    }

    $full_name = $details['first_name']." ".$details['second_name'];
    $email = $details['email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ('".$full_name."', '".$email."')";
}
```

## Leave the formatting up to the controller and just take the input and put it blindly into db

```
public function insertUser($full_name = false, $email = false){
    if(!$full_name || !$email){
        return false;
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ('".$full_name."', '".$email."')";
}
```

## Something else?

My problem is that I've got a lot of data to put into a table, so I don't really want to have each field as a separate arg of a function. But then I feel that putting in an array of info into the model requires me to check each index and format appropriately anyway, so there's not much point doing it in the controller as well. Seems like twice the work.

But then again, it doesn't feel right doing it in the model either!

So what do other people do?

P.S. The question is based on (but by no means limited to) the codeigniter framework.

Comment: Why not use your model object to represent a single record of the corresponding database table? You would have class variables representing each field and set them whenever you like; an insert() method would insert whatever is in those variables, etc.

Comment: Hmm, sounds plausible. Although my question was a general one, it was based on my use of codeigniter, a framework which doesn't appear to have the functionality for that structure. Your solution does seem interesting, but at the same time if codeigniter doesn't support it I assume that there are better ways to do it?

Comment: I think CodeIgniter does allow you to do this. Notice in the documentation for a model, they have class-level variables representing fields in the database: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: hmm it would appear that its half way there. I suppose it can probably be achieved if there was a function within a model to choose a different record (or create a new one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go again ...

Model in MVC is **not a class**. It is a layer which contains objects with two kinds of responsibilities:

- domain business logic
- data access and storage

Domain business objects should not have any clue where the data comes from or where it is stored. That means there is no SQL in domain objects, because it is quite possible that there isn't even a database and all the information goes into some remote REST API.

If you are using a database, then SQL would end up in the DAO's ( usually implementing [datamapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) ).

And formating is not responsibility of neither of domain objects , nor data access objects nor even controllers.

Formating should happen in the Views, which are a full-blown objects in MVC, and not some anemic templates. View is responsible for presentational logic. It requests from the domain model layer what it needs.

You really must look up what MVC Model2 is , and how it is different from MVP.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your object as a User, then your model should encapsulate all information about a User including their name and email - though I would generally split name into first name and last name rather than just having one name field. If you have lots of fields for a particular model - you should perhaps consider is it really just one model?

Your model should match whats in your persistence layer and then ideally you should sit an ORM under your models. This abstracts you away from using a particular database vendors logic, and to a certain extent abstracts you away from worrying about writing SQL queries and so on.

For example, with Doctrine (a PHP ORM) you can pass alot of your filtering and validation to the ORM using annotations. This is the same for many ORMs out there e.g. Hibernate for Java.

It takes quite a lot of effort to get the ORM setup properly, but it is worth it once you get there and can make your code significantly more elegant and clean.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although my question was a general one I am currently using the codeigniter php framework (which has a database class). I don't think that it is possible to create models as you suggest - although as you and @imm have suggested - it does seem like a much better idea. Do you have any information with specifics to codeigniter?

Comment: To be honest, CodeIgniter is something I haven't ever really used before, although googling found this http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Using_Doctrine_with_Code_Igniter. Doctrine is just one ORM - there is loads more - but Doctrine is one of the biggest.

Comment: If you're looking for an ORM for CodeIgniter -- Doctrine is a monstrous creature. I recommend checking out [DataMapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/).